# IOS: How to read specific data in one list of XML

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

When I use NSXMLParser to parse XML in iPhone app, I know how to do it in the scenario like this:

```
> <title>L3178 : Freiensteinau Richtung Grebenhain</title> // From XML
```

But, if I want to extract data from a list, e.x. I want to get the lat and lon from <>id>, how should I deal with that?

<>id>
http://www.freiefahrt.info/?id=468B0243-E15C-4580-9AD2 14D8CF692999&lon=9.3495&lat=50.49465&country=DE&filter=0&expires=2013-12-20T03:13:00
<>/id>

It is very strange if I use  instead of <>id>, it will disappear. So, I have to use this ugly notation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method which extracts parameters from urlString

```
- (NSDictionary *)paramsFromURLString:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"?"];
    NSString *subString = [urlString substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];

    NSArray *components = [subString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *string in components) {
        NSRange subRange = [string rangeOfString:@"="];
        NSString *key = [string substringToIndex:subRange.location];
        NSString *value = [string substringFromIndex:subRange.location+subRange.length];

        [params setObject:value forKey:key];

    }
    return params;
}
```

From the params find the lat and lon

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.freiefahrt.info/?id=468B0243-E15C-4580-9AD2 14D8CF692999&lon=9.3495&lat=50.49465&country=DE&filter=0&expires=2013-12-20T03:13:00";
NSDictionary *params = [self paramsFromURLString:urlString];

NSString *latitude = params[@"lat"];
NSString *longitude = params[@"lon"];
```